# How to suspend and resume a POSIX thread in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, resume

As I came to know creating and terminating thread abruptly
 using pthread_kill() everytime is not a good way to do, so I am going
 with suspend and resume method for a thread using `thread1.suspend()` and
 `thread1.resume()`, whenever needed. How to do/implement this?

Take below LED blinking code for reference. During `thread1.start()` creating thread with `suspended = false;` is continuing as it is stuck in a while loop. 
 Calling thread1.suspend() has no effect.

```
#define on 1
#define off 0
void gpio_write(int fd, int value);
void* led_Flash(void* args);


class PThread {
    public:

    pthread_t threadID;
    bool suspended;
    int fd;
    pthread_mutex_t m_SuspendMutex;
    pthread_cond_t m_ResumeCond;

    void start() {
        suspended = false;
        pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, led_Flash, (void*)this );
    }

    PThread(int fd1) { this->fd=fd1; }
    ~PThread() { }

    void suspend() {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m_SuspendMutex);
        suspended = true;
        printf("suspended\n");
        do {
            pthread_cond_wait(&m_ResumeCond, &m_SuspendMutex);
        } while (suspended);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_SuspendMutex);
    }

    void resume() {
        /* The shared state 'suspended' must be updated with the mutex held. */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m_SuspendMutex);
        suspended = false;
        printf("Resumed\n");
        pthread_cond_signal(&m_ResumeCond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_SuspendMutex);
    }
};

void* led_Flash(void* args)
{  
    PThread* pt= (PThread*) args;
    int ret=0;
    int fd= pt->fd;

       while(pt->suspended == false)
        {
        gpio_write(fd,on);
        usleep(1); 
        gpio_write(fd,off);
        usleep(1); 
        }   


return NULL;
}


int main()
{
    int fd1=1,fd2=2, fd3=3;

    class PThread redLED(fd1);
    class PThread amberLED(fd2);
    class PThread greenLED(fd3);

    redLED.start();
    amberLED.start();
    greenLED.start();

    sleep(1);
    redLED.suspend();

return 0;
}
```

**Could some body help me, please?**

Comment: Kill/suspend/resume all bad.  Try very hard to not do any of those things from user code.  Try very hard to arrange that the only time threads get created is at process startup and that the only time threads get killed is at process termination.

Comment: pt->suspended is neither volatile nor atomic. So my guess is the compiler optimized `while(pt->suspended == false) {...}` into `if (pt->suspended == false) { again: ...; goto again; }`. Volatile would be the right thing if the variable is changed from signal handlers. For multi-threading better use atomic.

Comment: "Calling thread1.suspend() has no effect." From reading the code I expect the red LED to continue blinking (see previous comment) and the main thread to simply get stuck there waiting for the resume condition. Is that correct? Did you want the suspend to block the main thread or did you want the led_Flash to stop until resumed? Currently led_Flash would simply exit the thread and there would be nothing to resume if ever it sees `pt->suspended == true`.

Comment: You can replace your `pthread_mutex_t` and `pthread_cond_t` with a single POSIX `sem_t`.  Then your `suspend()` becomes a simple `sem_wait()`, and `resume()` is a `sem_post()`.  Because all you're really doing is blocking.

Comment: The code is inherently C++ code because `class PThread { … };` and its contents is not valid C.  I've retagged and retitled appropriately.

Comment: @von  I want the led_Flash to stop blinking on calling suspend() until I call  resumed()

Comment: @von You are right  "nothing to resume resume if ever it sees pt->suspended == true"     But now I modified code , everything is working :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little modification of above code , it seems working . Thanks guy for pointing out issues on above code, the changes are as follow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include<iostream>
#define on 1
#define off 0
void gpio_write(int fd, int value);
void* led_Flash(void* args);


class PThread {
    public:

    pthread_t threadID;
    volatile int suspended;
    int fd;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    PThread(int fd1)
   {   
        this->fd=fd1; 
        this->suspended =1;  //Initial state: suspend blinking untill resume call 
        pthread_mutex_init(&this->lock,NULL); 
        pthread_create(&this->threadID, NULL, led_Flash, (void*)this );

    }
    ~PThread() 
    { 
      pthread_join(this->threadID , NULL);
      pthread_mutex_destroy(&this->lock);
    }

    void suspendBlink() {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&this->lock);
        this->suspended = 1;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&this->lock);
    }

    void resumeBlink() {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&this->lock);
        this->suspended = 0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&this->lock);
    }
};

void gpio_write(int fd, int value)
{
if(value!=0)
 printf("%d: on\n", fd);
else
 printf("%d: off\n", fd);
}


void* led_Flash(void* args)
{  
    PThread* pt= (PThread*) args;
    int fd= pt->fd;

    while(1)
    {
    if(!(pt->suspended))
        {
        gpio_write(fd,on);
        usleep(1); 
        gpio_write(fd,off);
        usleep(1);
        }
   }


return NULL;
}


int main()
{
   //Create threads with Initial state: suspend/stop blinking untill resume call 
    class PThread redLED(1);
    class PThread amberLED(2);
    class PThread greenLED(3);

    // Start blinking
    redLED.resumeBlink();
    amberLED.resumeBlink();
    greenLED.resumeBlink();
    sleep(5);

    // suspend/stop blinking
    amberLED.suspendBlink();

    sleep(5);

    redLED.suspendBlink();

    sleep(5);

    amberLED.suspendBlink();

    sleep(5);     

    redLED.resumeBlink();  


pthread_exit(NULL);

return 0;
}
```